# Este code me funciona normal si pongo un element html <input/>, pero no me funciona cuando uso el styleComponent, no me funciona el onChange

Tags: reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este code me funciona normal si pongo un element html , pero no me funciona cuando uso el styleComponent, no me funciona el onChange, ni onClick. he testeado ponerle eventos a styledComponents de tipo form o section y a esos si que les hala normalmente el evento como se debe, pero me da problemas con styledComponents de tipo input o button... no entiendo que está sucediendo acá T.T help me!

Comment: Podrías agregar el componente `Input`? Código, no una imagen

Comment: ya lo modifiqué bro, que pena no haber puesto todo mas detallado